# Tools to reverse engineer C++ ( i.e. to view C++ classes )

Tags: c++, webkit, reverse-engineering

I have a large body of hand-written C++ source (i.e. WebKit and other open source).

I want a tool which will:

- Let me see the inter-class relationships for each and any class:

  - Containment relationships: i.e. which other classes contain this class, or are contained by it (the header files declare templated smart pointer types as member data)
  - Declared dependencies (i.e. use of the type in method signatures; though I can see this pretty well using 'find in files')
  - Subclass and superclass hierarchies
- Run on Windows or Linux (or even a web-based solution)
- Preferably have a UI (or is that too much to ask?)
- Optionally be a plugin in an IDE

Unlike the related question, [C++ to UML (Reverse engineer / Round-trip engineering)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1407948/49942), I do NOT need it to:

- Parse the definitions/implementation (the cpp and c files)
- Support editing or 'round-tripping' the source

Instead, parsing the type declarations in the application and system headers (including template types and typedefs) would be enough. I have lists of all the header files.

I'd prefer it, if it could handle preprocessor definitions (especially #include and #if), but I can preprocess if that's necessary; and/or give it make or project files in various formats.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained and define what you mean by "reverse-engineering C++ source code".

Comment: Maybe use doxygen to autogenerate a usage graph. This would at least give you some information about the relations of classes. Note: I never used this feature but have in mind that this is possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB - I hope I've defined it. Please ask a specific question if something is unclear.

Comment: It sounds like you might want some dependency graph generation. I don't know any tools myself, but that might be worth searching for.

Comment: You want to depure the execution of a program and get a tool that converts the binary code into relationships within the source code that generated it?

Comment: @IanMedeiros - I have the source code. I want it to process source code (not decompile a binary).

Comment: I'm not sure that "reverse engineer" is the right word. Revere engineering is getting some knowledge which is hidden (in the binary). Here you got all the source code, and you need to understand it. "Refactoring" or "Source navigation" or "Source metrics" is more appropriate terminology

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Source_code and [30,000 Google results for `"reverse engineer c++" ide or tool`](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22reverse+engineer+c%2B%2B%22+ide+or+tool)

Answer (score 2):

You could always use doxygen, it'll give you full documentation on your set of header (inheritance, usage, ...) It can also generate graphs out of the class hierarchy.

Comment: doxygen will give you these informations even if no comments are available.

Comment: Doxygen is indeed able to find keyword (like class, ...) so you should be able to get something out of it

Answer (score 1):

another possibility is to **customize your own tool**, by **extending an existing C++ compiler**

There are two compilers which you could extend:

- [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) & Clang (but I can't help, because I don't know much them).
- [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (version *4.6* please) is extensible thru **plugins** or by coding a **MELT extension** [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is a high-level domain specific language to extend the GCC compiler; it is easier to code your extension in MELT than a plugin in C. [I am the main author of MELT]

Extending GCC is in my (biased) view the good way to do it. But I do admit that (even with t he help of MELT) it is non-trivial, because you need to partly understand GCC main internal representations (Gimple, Tree) and internal passes. (I guess that you have same issue with LLVM/Clang: to extend it you need to understand it).

GCC extensions (in MELT) or plugins (in C) are mostly working on the Gimple representations (after template expansion).

If interested in using MELT, feel free to ask more to me.

Some costly proprietary tools exist, like e.g. [coverity](http://coverity.com/) - but there are so expensive that I have no idea of what they are able to do.

Comment: I want something that's user-friendly, with a UI: maybe an IDE plugin.

Comment: I heard that Coverity is a costly proprietary tool with a web user interface.

Comment: @Basile: I'm very interested in MELT, see my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042991/c-dependency-tracking-tool-reverse-engineering Is MELT capable of doing what I want? Thanks!

Comment: MELT is an infrastructure and a domain specific language to extend GCC (perhaps I should tell it is the "awk" or the "perl" of GCC internal representations). So you can extend GCC with MELT, but you have to write some small MELT code to achieve your needs. The `gcc-melt@googlegroups.com` list is a better place to ask.