# C++: Dependency tracking tool (reverse engineering)

Tags: c++, dependencies

My question is different from though similar to the ones such as:

[Tools to reverse engineer C++ ( i.e. to view C++ classes )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312328/tools-to-reverse-engineer-c-i-e-to-view-c-classes)

Instead of looking for class diagrams, I'm more interested in finding call chains and dependencies and generating nice-looking graphs.

Is there such a tool? I know **cscope** and **ctags** can do a little bit of what I'd like to do but in very much low-level interactive manners (one query at a time). I'd like something more automated, e.g., given an API, find all its sub-routine call paths till it reaches the leaf and show them to me.

Is there a tool for this already?
Is it possible to do it at the binary level? like reverse-engineering function dependencies in a library (.a, .so, .dll as input)?

**EDIT:**

I prefer static analysis tool over profilers since I would like it to work for library and module code as well.

Also I prefer cross-platform solutions. I'm mainly on a Mac but tools for Linux or Windows will be interesting as well.

**UPDATE**

After researching into the recommendations I decided that Doxygen is what I want. It gives caller and callee graphs, and uses static analysis, cross-platform, and free.

Thanks to all the other recommendations. They opened my eyes quite a bit.

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind with the callgrind tool?

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be on the profiler route as gprof does. More useful for debugging a program.

Comment: Promoted my comments about valgrind into an answer, as nobody mentioned them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen can display caller and callee trees:
[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

**Edit 1:**
[image: Example Doxygen call trees]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know Doxygen can do more than generating docs. I'll have to test its robustness though. Curious, is there an example (e.g., graph) showing the result?

Comment: @kakyo:  See my latest edit 1.

Answer (score 3):

CppDepend looks totally awesome for the task.

[image]

http://www.cppdepend.com/

Comment: Thanks. Looks very polished and probably the closest to what I want as an all-around analyzer. Too bad it's so pricy! Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DEPENDS application which detects most of C C++ and C# libraries in windows.
but still wont give you call chains...
here's the link [DEPENDS](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting. Pity that it only works for Windows. Although it's not exactly what I was looking for. It may be useful later. Hope it gives more than Dumpbin. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use `CodeTune`, it will give you call graph showing function dependencies

http://www.thewallsoft.com/codetune-documentation/

On GNU/Linux you can use `gprof` and then this visualizer to create your call graph

http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/XDot#Screenshots

Comment: The linux toolset seems very interesting. It also brought graphviz to me. Didn't know about this tool either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Promoted from comment.**

Have you tried using valgrind with the [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) tool?

Valgrind is useful for debugging but the callgrind tool inside valgrind is very useful for profiling and knowing which functions calls which other functions. It comes with a visual tool called [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) that allows you to see as blocks inside other blocks the function calls.

And it's **absolutely free**.

[image]